# Greater than on multiple columns / lexicographic where with order

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, pagination, tuples

I'm writing a query to be used for pagination, where a typical page would be returned by a query like:

```
SELECT col_a, col_b
WHERE (col_a = 'value_a' AND col_b > 'value_b') OR (col_a > 'value_a')
ORDER BY col_a, col_b
LIMIT 50
```

It slightly surprises me that there isn't a neater way to make the `WHERE` clause with less repetition. Is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: there is a different/clearer way. You can compare "tuples" (this may not be the proper term)

```
WHERE (col_a, col_b) > ('value_a', 'value_b')
```

I don't know if this effects likelihood of index use.

Comment: It *does* affect index usage. The way you wrote it, a multicolumn index can be used in an index scan *and* make sorting unnecessary. It cannot be used as effectively with the original query (only with a bitmap index scan and a following sort).