# SQL tuple/lexicographic comparison with multiple directions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to return elements from a database query based on an inequality using the lexicographic ordering on multiple columns.  As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688349/greater-than-on-multiple-columns-lexicographic-where-with-order) this is straightforward if I'm comparing all the columns in the same direction.  Is there a straigtforward way to do this if I want to reverse the direction of the sort on some columns.

For instance, I might have columns A, B and C and values 5, 7, and 23 and I'd like to return something like:

WHERE A < 5 OR (A = 5 AND B > 7) OR (A = 5 AND B = 7 AND C < 23)

Is there any easier way to do this using tuples (I have to construct in a function without knowing the number of columns beforehand)?  Note that, some columns are DateTime columns so I can't rely on tricks that apply only to integers (e.g. negating both sides).  I'm happy to use postgresql specific tricks.

And, if not, is there a specific way/order I should build expressions like the above to best use multicolumn indexes?

Comment: Refering to the thread you mentioned, can you try the diea ````WHERE (col_a, 'value_b') > ('value_a', col_b)````

Comment: I'm an idiot!  For some reason I assumed you couldn't mix constant's and variables in a tuple.  I should have guessed SQL doesn't distinguish variables and other terms syntactically like that.  Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In my defense, I was very tired.

Comment: You are not alone. While it should work most SQL, there are always old-school languages won't let you put variable to the right. that's why I wasn't sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the thread you mentioned, can you try the idea `WHERE (col_a, 'value_b') > ('value_a', col_b)`

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking if going the CTE route and creating a column which stores 0 or 1 for whether the data passes the specific filter criteria or not.

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT 
      ..,
      ...,
      CASE 
        WHEN A < 5 THEN 1
        WHEN A = 5 AND B > 7 THEN 1
        WHEN A = 5 AND B = 7 AND C < 23 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS filter_criteria 
   )


SELECT
  ..,
  ..
FROM 
  CTE
WHERE filter_criteria = 1
```

OR, directly applying the CASE statement in the WHERE clause. This reduces the extra step of CTE

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
            WHEN A < 5 THEN 1
            WHEN A = 5 AND B > 7 THEN 1
            WHEN A = 5 AND B = 7 AND C < 23 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
```